# Number of elements of a finite group with the identity $x^2=e$ for all elements.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How many elements can have a group $G$ with $x^2=e$ for all elements $x\in G$? Here $e$ is the identity element of the group.

I know that a group with such an identity is commutative. A possible proof is this one:
$$
(ab)^2=e; \quad abab=e; \quad abab^2=b; \quad aba=b; \quad aba^2=ba; \quad ab=ba.
$$
Furthermore, since
$$
(x_i x_j)x_j = x_i (x_j x_j) = x_i,
$$
and
$$
(x_i x_j)x_i=(x_j x_i)x_i = x_j(x_i x_i) = x_j,
$$
the following conditions must be fulfilled:
$$
x_i x_j=x_k \Rightarrow x_k x_j=x_i,
$$
$$
x_i x_j=x_k \Rightarrow x_k x_i=x_j.
$$
What should I do next? Is it possible to give an example of such a group with any finite number of elements? Or is there a restriction to this number?

Comment: Do you know [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20group%20theory,an%20element%20of%20order%20p.)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=|G|$. We will prove that $n$ must be of the form $n=2^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, and, conversely, that for any $k\in\mathbb N$ there is a group of order $n=2^k$ satisfying the identity $x^2=e$.

The necessity is proven using induction on $n$.

- Obviously, if $n=1$, then $n=2^0$.
- Let's now suppose $n>1$ and choose an arbitrary element $a\in G, a\ne e$. As $a^2=e$, the set $H=\{e, a\}$ is a subgroup of order $2$, and $G$ being Abelian (as you have already concluded), $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so we can create the quotient group $G/H$. Now, $|G/H|=|G|/|H|=n/2<n$ *and* (as it is easy to check), the identity $x^2=e/H$ is valid in $G/H$, so $n/2=2^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$ (as per induction hypothesis). Thus, $n=2^{k+1}$.

The converse is easy, a group of order $2^k$ which satisfies $x^2=e$ is, for example, $\mathbb Z_2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

You deduced that $G$ is abelian. Hence if it is finite it is isomorphic to a (finite) direct product of cyclic groups. From this, it is easy to see that if $G$ is finite, then
$$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_2^n$$
for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. However, a group $G$ satisfying your property need not be finite, for instance
$$G = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_2$$
is infinite but satisfies your property.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers:

In any group $G$, finite or infinite, if the set $X = \{x \in G : x^2 = 1\}$ is finite, then $|X|$ is even or $|X| = 1$. You can find a proof on several questions at Math.SE, but this is a good exercise. For infinite groups it is slightly more difficult.

Conversely for any even integer $n > 0$, you can find a dihedral group $G$ such that $|X| = n$. This also a good exercise.

Comment: The question was not about the possible number of elements satisfying $x^2=e$ in an arbitrary group, it was about the possible order of a group in which every element satisfies $x^2=e$.